# Unable to add tapgesture for tableview cell image in swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I am using [GSImageViewerController](https://github.com/wxxsw/GSImageViewerController) this pod for imageview tap gesture.. which is working in viewcontroller

but i need tapgesture for tableview cell image so here i am getting error:

total code:

```
import UIKit
import GSImageViewerController
class tableviewViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var imageView: UIImageView!
var nameArray = ["hewjkew", "uhrueihriu", "jfkejfkefn", "ueyduieh", "uydhuegfhejh"]
var imageArray = ["fla.png","fla.png","fla.png","fla.png","fla.png"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

 @objc func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return nameArray.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: imageArray[indexPath.row])
    
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    cell.imageView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.imageView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    return cell
}

@objc func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! UITableViewCell

    let imageInfo = GSImageInfo(image: (cell.imageView?.image!)!, imageMode: .aspectFit)
    let transitionInfo = GSTransitionInfo(fromView: (cell.imageView)!)

    let imageViewer    = GSImageViewerController(imageInfo: imageInfo, transitionInfo: transitionInfo)

    present(imageViewer, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

here in this line `let imageInfo = GSImageInfo(image: (cell.imageView?.image!)!, imageMode: .aspectFit)` at exclamation mark i am getting below error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

please how to fix this. please do help with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! UITableViewCell
```

outside of `cellForRowAt` (you used it in `imageTapped` ) and replace

```
let imageInfo = GSImageInfo(image: (cell.imageView?.image!)!, imageMode: .aspectFit)
```

with

```
let imageV = tapGestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView // access the current clicked image cell
let imageInfo = GSImageInfo(image:imageV.image!, imageMode: .aspectFit)
```

as `cell.imageView?.image!` is properly nil for a dequeued cell

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! UITableViewCell
let imageInfo = GSImageInfo(image: (cell.imageView?.image!)!, imageMode: .aspectFit)
```

You are accessing the `image` of a *dequeued* table view cell. Normally you'd only dequeue a reusable cell when you need a new cell. `dequeueReusableCell` will either give you an existing cell that is not used, or create a new cell for you if the "queue" is empty. It just so happens that it creates a new cell for you, and for a new cell, its image view doesn't have an image!

You should instead get the image of the image view of the cell that is tapped. Since you add the gesture recogniser to the image view directly, you can access it by `tapGestureRecognizer.view`:

```
guard let image = (tapGestureRecognizer.view as? UIImageView).image else { return }
let imageInfo = GSImageInfo(image: image, imageMode: .aspectFit)
// ...
```

Also, since the table cells are reused, you should remove any old gesture recognisers before adding a new one:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: imageArray[indexPath.row])
    
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    
    // Add this line!
    cell.imageView?.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()

    cell.imageView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.imageView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    return cell
}
```